# I have an array of index and varieties and I want to make a list of possible permutations

Tags: javascript, permutation

I want to write a function to make a list of permutations based on my rule, each index can have a number as value, and the index in the outcome should not be duplicated, so as it follows:
I have an Array like this:

```
[
  { index: 'a', varieties: [ 10 ] },
  { index: 'b', varieties: [ 5 ] },
  { index: 'c', varieties: [ 5, 8 ] },
  { index: 'd', varieties: [ 2, 6 ] },
]
```

and my outcome will be an array like this:

```
[
  'a10b5c5d2',
  'a10b5c5d6',
  'a10b5c8d2',
  'a10b5c8d6'
]
```

I tried looping but it's a weird question and I don't get the concept, how to such thing. Sorry for Bad English

Comment: I don't understand how the input and output relate to each other

Comment: could you add the code that you tried ?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: You compute the combination of every index + each variety and concatenate them.

Comment: https://github.com/kiyui/permutatify

Comment: for example value "a" takes only one input which makes a10, and value "c" takes 2 input 5 and 8,  i want to make a string out of each combination which these 2 give a10c5 and a10c8. for all of my indexes, I will have something like a10b5c5d6, I'm not good at English, so sorry if I cant explain correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it's easier to think about this in terms of recursion. For every element and each variety of every element, you want to prepend `index + variety` to all combinations of the next array element etc.

```js
const data = [
  { index: 'a', varieties: [ 10 ] },
  { index: 'b', varieties: [ 5 ] },
  { index: 'c', varieties: [ 5, 8 ] },
  { index: 'd', varieties: [ 2, 6 ] },
];

function compute(data, i) {
  if (i === data.length) {
    return [''];
  }
  return data[i].varieties
    .map(v => compute(data, i+1).map(c => data[i].index + v + c))
    .flat();
}

console.log(compute(data, 0));
```

Comment: this makes perfect sense, the reason this concept was weird for me was I'm not really good with recursions, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the cartesian product without recursion.

```js
const
    data = [{ index: 'a', varieties: [10] }, { index: 'b', varieties: [5] }, { index: 'c', varieties: [5, 8] }, { index: 'd', varieties: [2, 6] }],
    result = data
        .map(({ index, varieties }) => varieties.map(v => index + v))
        .reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []))
        .map(a => a.join(''));

console.log(result);
```